# SQL Server What size is VLDB

Tags: sql-server, vldb

Is it 1TB minimum or is it 2?

My current client has sub 1 TB and I wanted to know if I write that they are on the verge of a re-classification due to their size they should consider these BOATLOAD of issues.

:)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

In my opinon its the classic answer, it depends. Rather than focus on a fixed size i would look at how the application is performing now and does it warrant the additional complexity. Then pick those techniques that fix the problems you experience.

Basically its the old addage, don't optimise your solution prematurely.

Comment: There are so many wrong issues with this db.  It is a complex situation just like every other location :)

Poor Vendor application capabilities lead to table scans in all reporting output.  Massive row counts make this unpleasant.

Comment: It not a unique situation, but assuming that 3rd party software is involved your hands could be tied to some extent. I would say from the limited details it would be a good start to manage the expectations and start the analysis stage, then give them some options because at the end of the day its a business choice on what reporting they want and how much they want to pay for it.